# How to verify if link is enabled or not in selenium webdriver using JAVA?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I want to verify if a pagination link is enabled or not first. If it
is enabled then click on the link, else i don't want to click on the
link and skip the if condition in JAVA.

I am using selenium web-driver and TestNG.

Thanks,
Rishil Bhatt

Comment: Can you post the HTML code when link is "enabled" and when it's "disabled". I'm trying to understand what you mean by saying "enabled". Usually it's either there or not, you cannot really disable it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void elementIsDisable(WebDriver driver, By by) throws Exception {
    WebElement disable = driver.findElement(by);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    String disableAttribute = disable.getAttribute("disabled");
    Assert.assertEquals("true", disableAttribute);
}
```

Then call the method in your test:

```
homePage.elementIsDisable(driver, By.id("acc-confirm"));
```

This check if the webElement is disable

Answer (score 0):

Using web console of your browser inspect element to check if there is any attribute to disable the link using style, class etc.

```
String temp = selenium.getAttribute(locator@attribute);
```

Now you can verify the value of temp.

Pls refer this as well : http://www.seleniumtests.com/2011/06/selenium-tutorial-get-attribute-for.html

Answer (score 0):

use isEditable(locator), if the link is disabled the will return false else true

Answer (score 0):

```
if(existsElement("test")==true){
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("test"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
else{
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
```